# PostgreSql pass array argument in WHERE NOT

Tags: postgresql

I have a sql function that creates a materialized view:

```
CREATE FUNCTION reports_mt_views(exclude_ids int[]) RETURNS void AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW tx_materialized AS
        SELECT tx.transaccion_id AS tx_transaccion_id,
        ...
        WHERE  creation_date > (current_date - interval '' 3 month '')
        AND (account_id <> ALL (' || $1 || '))'
RETURN;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```

I also tried as:

```
AND account_id NOT IN ' || $1|| ')'
```

But it does not work. When I execute:

```
SELECT reports_mt_views(ARRAY [1,2,8,538524]);
```

I have this error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: text || integer[]
LINE 171:     AND (account_id <> ALL (' || $1 || '))'
                                         ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

There is not a problem with the array itself I tested it with a FOR loop and works. But into the condition it does not. What I have missed here?

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name I also tried with expressions but the result is the same the problem seems to be that the clause requires something like (1,2,8,538524) and the array is [1,2,8,538524]. I need this way because the materialized view have to ignore those accounts ids.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to concanate the array as a text then it can be readby the clause *where not in*.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pps.reports_mt_views(exclude_ids integer[])
...
DECLARE
    in_accounts ALIAS FOR $1;
    out_accounts  TEXT;
BEGIN
    out_accounts := in_accounts;
    out_accounts := trim(leading '{' FROM out_accounts);
    out_accounts := trim(trailing '}' FROM out_accounts);
```

And it can be used as:

```
WHERE (orden.cuenta_id NOT IN (' || out_accounts || '))
```